# What's the best way to prevent React app being scraped?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm still very new to React so forgive me if the question is too naive. To my understand, React usually requires an API to do XHR requests. So someone with very basic tech background can easily figure out what the api looks like by looking at the network tab in web browser's debug console.

For example, people might find a page that calls to api `https://www.example.com/product/1`, then they can just do brute force scraping on product id 1 - 10000 to get data for all products.

```
https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/1
https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/2
https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/3
https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/4
https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/5
https://www.example.com/api/v1/product/6
...
```

Even with user auth, one can just use same cookie or token when they login to make the call and get the data.

So what is the best way to prevent scraping on React app? or maybe the api shouldn't be designed as such, hence I'm just asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions to address the issue you're facing:

1. This is a common problem. You need to solve it by using id's that are GUID's and not sequentially generated integers.
2. Restricting to the same-origin won't work because someone can make a request through Postman or Insomnia or Curl.
3. You can also introduce rate-limiting
4. In addition, you can invalidate your token after a certain number of requests or require it to be renewed after every 10 requests

Answer (score 0):

I think no matter what you do to the JavaScript code, reading your API endpoint is the easiest thing in the world(Wireshark is an easy, bad example), once it is called upon from the browser. Expect it to be public, with that said, protecting it it is easier than you might anticipate.

1. **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** is your friend

   Only allow requests to come from given urls. This may or may not allow GET requests but it will always allow direct access on GET routes. Keep that in mind.

---

PHP Example

```
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
$allowed_domains = [
    'http://mysite1.com',
    'https://www.mysite2.com',
    'http://www.mysite2.com',
];

if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
}
```

---

2. Use some form of **token** that can be validated

   This is another conventional approach, and you can find more about this here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Cheers!